# RxJava instead of AsyncTask?

Tags: java, android, concurrency, android-asynctask, rx-java

I came across several instances when people were trying to persuade me into using RxJava instead of Android's standard `AsyncTask` construct.

In my opinion RxJava offers a lot more features but loses in simplicity against `AsyncTask`.

Are there any use cases that suit one approach better than the other or even more general can RxJava even be considered superior?

Comment: I saw this article explains why, if it helps. http://blog.feedpresso.com/2016/01/25/why-you-should-use-rxjava-in-android-a-short-introduction-to-rxjava.html

Comment: Thanks. It looks a bit like how Scala handles concurrency. I'll do some test runs in my projects to get used to RxJava. However do you think there is a fundamental flaw with AsyncTask's functionality?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The full power of RxJava is visible when you use it on Java 8, preferably with a library like Retrofit. It allows you to trivially chain operations together, with full control of error handling. For example, consider the following code given `id`: an int that specifies the order and apiClient: a Retrofit client for the order management microservice:

```
apiClient
.getOrder(id)
.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
.flatMapIterable(Order::getLineItems)
.flatMap(lineItem ->
    apiClient.getProduct(lineItem.getProductId())
             .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
             .map(product -> product.getCurrentPrice() * lineItem.getCount()),
    5)
.reduce((a,b)->a+b)
.retryWhen((e, count) -> count<2 && (e instanceof RetrofitError))
.onErrorReturn(e -> -1)
.subscribe(System.out::println);
```

This will asynchronously calculate the total price of an order, with the following properties:

- at most 5 requests against the API in flight at any one time (and you can tweak the IO scheduler to have a hard cap for all requests, not just for a single observable chain)
- up to 2 retries in case of network errors
- -1 in case of failure (an antipattern TBH, but that's an other discussion)

Also, IMO the `.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())` after each network call should be implicit - you can do that by modifying how you create the Retrofit client. Not bad for 11+2 lines of code, even if it's more backend-ish than Android-ish.

Comment: Thank you very much for this detailed example. I'm looking forward to tinker with those first-class functions. Haven't been doing this for a long time in Java.

Comment: I'd rahter have 5x the number of lines of code, and have it more easily understood and maintained.  Rx has its uses, but chaining makes incomprehensible write only code like this.

Answer (score 3):

RxBinding/RxAndroid by Jake Wharton provides some nice threading functionality that you can use to make async calls but RxJava provides waaay more benefits/functionality than just dealing with async threading. That said, There is a pretty steep learning curve (IMO). Also, it should be noted that there is nothing wrong with using AsyncTasks, you can just write more eloquent solutions with Rx (also, IMO).

TLDR you should make an effort to use it. Retrofit and RxJava work together nicely for your AsyncTask replacement purposes.

Comment: Cool. So would you say that AsyncTask is fine for rather small projects like a simple HTTP handler?

Comment: Absolutely, but you can accomplish the same things with RxJava/RxBinding/RxAndroid and you might get some cool points for doing it that way.

Comment: Very nice. I'm always looking for elegance. ;-)