# Spring RxJava2CrudRepository not saving until call on return

Tags: spring-boot, rx-java

i am using springboot with the new RxJava2CrudRepository
i observed that when i call

```
parkingContentRepo.save(new ParkingContent());
```

nothing gets written to the db.
when i call

```
parkingContentRepo.save(new ParkingContent()).blockingGet();
```

the entry is written.

maybe this is a stupid question. but why should i make this call to blockingGet ( i suppose subscribe would also work ) ?

this makes the api more difficult to use. if someone forgets the call, nothing is persisted.

Answer (score 1):

When using Observables, Flowables, or any other reactive-streams API, you need to keep in mind that in most of the cases unless you subscribe, the operations won't start. In your case, `.blockingGet()` is internally subscribing to the reactive object that `save` returns.

Why is this so? Because this allows you to easily compose operations while retaining the ability to adjust asynchronicity based on your requirements.

This makes it [easier to work with external APIs without blocking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39214073/rxjava-instead-of-asynctask-pros-and-cons), but harder to use when you have very isolated islands of asynchronous/reactive code.