# Use Of Async Task and Thread pool executors

Tags: android, performance

Currently am working on an application which using `AsyncTask` and `Thread pool` executors to perform all the network operations.

With the modern day practices in android application development, It is not recommended.

Moreover application architecture is also not well defined.Is it advisable to define MVP and use either `Loaders` or `RXJAVA` for Asynchronous operations?

Comment: This is off topic, as its 100% personal opinion.  As long as you understand the drawbacks, any of those approaches can work.  All have different drawbacks.  Use the one your proefer.

Comment: I have asked this question because, the current application makes it really hard to go with further enhancements. I wanted to know if anyone has come across situations where they have redesigned the application to support further enhancements and integrate more business use cases. As, and when application grows.

Comment: I understand, and its not a stupid/bad question.  Its just not on topic for this site.

Comment: Thanks a lot, can you please suggest any such platform which encourages discussion on these topics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using RX makes little to no difference in runtimes in my opinion. Really what makes up the runtime is the operation inside that background task you are trying to compute.

While it is still ok to just use AsyncTasks and everybody can do what they usually do, introducing RX goes beyond just background tasks. You get a world of new opportunities and powerful ways you can functionally pipe your workflow and operations. There are many many things you can do with RX that you can’t do with AysncTasks.

here is full explaination which one you should you AsyncTask or RxJava

https://medium.com/@davethomas_9528/asynctask-vs-rx-in-a-small-use-case-f75ddc57ebe3

https://stackoverflow.com/a/39215031/9024123

Comment: Thanks it provided me a better clarity